# How to find Database Server Name

Tags: sql-server, database

I have no idea about databases, and I googled but couldn't figure out. I'm running database on my machine. Is the 'database server name' localhost?

Comment: `select @@SERVERNAME`

Comment: I' m running Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, how do I run that command? Thanks!

Comment: just copy paste `select @@servername` and run it in `SQL Server Management Studio` you will get the server name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes "localhost" works and will connect to the default database instance (assuming once exists).  Or "127.0.0.1" works.  Or "." works too in many scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, in the Object Explorer pane, right click the server and select properties. In the pane, there should be a heading called "Connection" and in that heading a link to a new window called "View connection properties". The value next to "Server name" is the name of your server.